# GCP Dataflow +Apache beam - Http SOAP xml API to external on-prem webservice

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Does GCP Dataflow support transformation of calling external API endpoint using SOAP xml POST?
I couldn't find any Apache Beam library supporting this need directly.
If not SOAP, can I do REST API callouts through Apache Beam transformations?

Comment: Make the API request inside a DoFn

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do api calls in a `DoFn`.
You only need using your api client class inside the DoFn and process your call.

You should care about performance in this case, due to network access of your api calls.

If you have the possibility to retrieve the data from the api directly in the input connector (IO), you will have better performances.

Comment: What do you mean with "if you have the possibility to retrieve the data from the api directly in the input connector (IO)" , Could you explain a little more about this topic?